# How to avoid this `for`loop to operate with a list

Tags: r, for-loop, case

I have a problem with R, because I need to do some operations on a list and create a new dataframe with those values from the list.
If I use a for loop it takes very long time to do.
And don't know how to avoid that for loop, and how to do that "if + case_when" without that for loop.

In the code below there are comments to explain what I do and what happends.

Thanks a lot!!

```
#search in all rows of list "total"
for(i in 1:nrow(total)) {

  #Take with total$Cad[[i]] a value from another list
  val1 <- posdi[posdi$cad == str_to_upper(total$Cad[[i]]),]

  #Check if "font" value from val1 is equal to "Taake" and take the value
  val2 <- val1[val1$font == "Taake",]

  #Format date value
  thedate <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(total$TheDate[[i]], format="%Y-%m-%d"), '%Y%m%d'))

  #And here comes where I can't continue easily. I want to do an IF and make a different 
  #case_when if the result is between 1 and 5 or between 6 and 7
  if(total$dia[[i]] >= 1 & total$dia[[i]] <= 5) {
    fran = case_when(
      total$secs[[i]]>=0 & total$secs[[i]]<1.5 ~ 1,
      total$secs[[i]]>=1.5 & total$secs[[i]]<4 ~ 2,
      total$secs[[i]]>=4 & total$secs[[i]]<8 ~ 3,
      total$secs[[i]]>=8 & total$secs[[i]]<10 ~ 4)
  } else {
    fran = case_when(
      total$secs[[i]]>=0 & total$secs[[i]]<1.5 ~ 5,
      total$secs[[i]]>=1.5 & total$secs[[i]]<4 ~ 6,
      total$secs[[i]]>=4 & total$secs[[i]]<8 ~ 7,
      total$secs[[i]]>=8 & total$secs[[i]]<10 ~ 8)
  }
  
  #and finally, add that "fran" value, those three from the beggining and some from total list to a new dataframe
  datosTel[nrow(datosTel) + 1,] = c(val2$cad, str_to_upper(total$Camp[[i]]), total$numsem[[i]], thedate, total$diasem[[i]], fran, 0)
}
#It works with the "for" loop, but it take so much time (it goes one by one and the list has more than 200K rows).
#How can I do it without that for loop and make the "if + case_when" correctly?
```

Thanks again and have a good day

As said before, my problems are the FOR loop and that IF and CASE_WHEN inside the FOR, because I don't know how to do it if there is no loop

Comment: Have a look at the `purrr` package.

Comment: Are you sure you have a list at hand and not a data.frame? If its a data.frame, you can have a look at the ```dplyr``` and the functions Konrad mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside your loop only touches the current element (`[[i]]`), and all operations you are performing are vectorised by default (except for the `if`, but we can replace that directly by `if_else`).

So you can replace the entire loop with a `mutate` or `transmute` statement (they do the same, `transmute` just does not keep existing columns, so it seems more appropriate in your case).

Furthermore, you can simplify the `if` by merging the two branches and adding an offset that depends on `total$dia`.

Lastly, your `case_when` expression happens to be expressible as a `findInterval` expression.

In the following I am assuming that `datosTel` is an empty table before your loop, and I am also making some assumptions about the column names which you may need to adjust.

```
datosTel = total %>%
  transmute(
    cad = posdi$cad[posdi$cad == str_to_upper(Cad) & posdi$font == "Taake"],
    Camp = str_to_upper(Camp),
    numsem = numsem,
    thedate = as.numeric(format(as.Date(TheDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), '%Y%m%d')),
    diasem = diasem,
    offset = if_else(dia >= 1 & dia <= 5, 0, 4),
    fran = offset + findInterval(secs, c(0, 1.5, 4, 8, 10, Inf)),
    LAST_COLUMN = 0
  ) %>%
  select(-offset)
```

(Replace `LAST_COLUMN` with the actual column name.)

The `findInterval` call is equvialent to:

```
    case_when(
      secs >= 0 & secs < 1.5 ~ 1,
      secs >= 1.5 & secs < 4 ~ 2,
      secs >= 4 & secs < 8 ~ 3,
      secs >= 8 & secs < 10 ~ 4
    )
```

Comment: Incidentally, the computation of `thedate` looks *very* dodgy but I’ve just copied your code here.

Comment: Thank you, @konrad-rudolph, it works!!
As you've seen, I'm newbie with R

Regards